# typeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, typeerror

I'm new to OpenCV trying to learn by my self I run this code form tutorial :

```
img=cv2.imread('whatever.jpg')  
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
edges=cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize=3)  
lines=cv2.HoughLines(gray,1,np.pi/180,200)  
for rho,theta in lines[0]:  
    a=np.cos(theta)  
    b=np.sin(theta)  
    x0=a*rho  
    y0=b*rho  
    x1=int(x0+1000*(-b))  
    y1=int(y0+1000*(a))  
    x2=int(x0-1000*(-b))
    y2=int(y0-1000*(a))  
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)
cv2.imwrite('somthing.jpg',img)
```

I get this **error** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "nothing", line 8, in <module>  
for rho,theta in lines[0]:  
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I looked for answer for this kind of problem but i didn't get the part `lines[0]`.
thanks for help

Comment: Check lines=cv2.HoughLines(gray,1,np.pi/180,200) should have returned None. and so lines[0] throwing error trying to access 0 index on None object

Comment: `cv2.HoughLines(gray,1,np.pi/180,200)` returned `None`. You probably want to look up the documentation to see why it did that.

Comment: it gives None, it's not the first mistake I find with this tutorial

Comment: @BasharHeeb: so perhaps the `cv2.imread()` call failed, on your system, because the current working directory doesn't contain the file it tried to load. The current working directory of your script may not be what you expected it to be, better to use the *full path* of the file. You can check what directory is the current working directory with `import os`, then `print(os.getcwd())`.

Comment: I think I found out what the problem, the code here is about finding lines in image but the image I chose has no lines to detect I tried to print each value, from "img, gray, edges" I get list that includes matrix with values when I get to lines I have list with empty matrix,it could be

Answer (score 0):

cv2 library functions do not always return value. You should check return values for,

```
img=cv2.imread('whatever.jpg')  
gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
edges=cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize=3)  
lines=cv2.HoughLines(gray,1,np.pi/180,200)
```

and you should add try-catch lines. If you give same error, try this.

```
img=cv2.imread(os.path.join(filePath,'image1.png'))
```